# Convert object to KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, keyvaluepair

I have an `IEnumerable<Entityclass>` for an entity that has a `string` and an `int` member. **i need to convert it to an array of `KeyValuePair<string, double>` and vice versa.**

It fails with a cast error.

```
[DataContract]
public class Entityclass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string text{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int textcount{ get; set; }
 }
```

I have `IEnumerable<Entityclass>`

- How do I convert from `IEnumerable<Entityclass>` to an array of `KeyvaluePair<string,
  double>[]`?
- How do I convert the `KeyvaluePair<string, double>[]` array to a `KeyvaluePair<string, int>[]` array ?
- How do I convert `KeyvaluePair<string, double>` back to an IEnumerable?

I have tried:

- `topics is IEnumerable<Entityclass>;`
- `topics.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, double>>().ToArray();`  Fails with cast error

Comment: question title should be fixed, its "convert a list or an Enumerable to an array of KeyValuePair" not a single object

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to *project* each topic into a `KeyValuePair`. The Linq `Select` extension method does that:

```
topics
    .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string, double>(x.text, x.textcount))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` has an extension called `ToDictionary`. This is a good starting point for our own `ToKeyValuePairs`.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>> ToKeyValuePairs<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>> pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>>();
    foreach (var element in source)
        pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element)));
    return pairs;

}
```

Now it is very easy to take any `IEnumerable` and convert it to `KeyValuePair` while specifying a key and value.

```
// Array of objects (tuples)
(string First, string Middle, string Last)[] tuples = new (string First, string Middle, string Last)[3];
tuples[0] = new("Micheal", "Joseph", "Jackson");
tuples[1] = new("Elvis", "Aaron", "Presley");
tuples[2] = new("Arnold", "Alois ", "Schwarzenegger");

// Convert only First and Last properties to KeyValuePairs.
var keyPairs = tuples.ToKeyValuePairs(a => a.First, a => a.Last);
```

In your case you just need to use the build in `.ToArray()`.

```
var keyPairs = tuples.ToKeyValuePairs(a => a.First, a => a.Last).ToArray();
```